# how to detach a shortcut command on Qooxdoo?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have this code:

```
qx.Class.define('my.Window', {
   extend: qx.ui.window.Window,

   construct: function(caption, icon) {
     this.base(arguments, caption, icon);
     this.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Basic());

     this.__btn = new qx.ui.form.Button('Shortcut Test');
     this.__cmd = new qx.ui.command.Command('Alt+T');

     this.__cmd.addListener("execute", function() { alert('FOOBAR'); });
     this.__btn.setCommand(this.__cmd);

     this.add(this.__btn);
 },

 members: {
   __btn: null,
   __cmd: null
 }
});

qx.Class.define('my.Compo', {
  extend: qx.ui.container.Composite,

  construct: function() {
    this.base(arguments);
    this.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.HBox());

    this.__btnShow = new qx.ui.form.Button("Show Window", "icon/22/apps/internet-web-browser.png");
    this.__btnDestroy = new qx.ui.form.Button('Destroy window');
    this.__btnNull = new qx.ui.form.Button('Null window');

    this.__btnDestroy.addListener('execute', function(){
      this.__window.destroy();
    }, this);

    this.__btnNull.addListener('execute', function(){
      this.__window = null;
    }, this);

    this.__btnShow.addListener("execute", function(e){
      if(this.__window) {
        console.info('Window exist');
        this.__window.open();
        this.__window.center();
      }
      else {
       console.info('Window do not exist!');
        this.__window = new my.Window("Shortcut test window");
        this.__window.setWidth(300);
        this.__window.setHeight(200);
        this.__window.setShowMinimize(false);
        this.__window.open();
        this.__window.center();
      }
    }, this);

    this.add(this.__btnShow);
    this.add(this.__btnDestroy);
    this.add(this.__btnNull);
  },

  members: {
    __btnShow: null,
    __btnDestroy: null,
    __window: null
  }
});

var compo = new my.Compo();
this.getRoot().add(compo);
```

So, if you try "Alt+T" shortcut before clicking "Show Window" button, nothing happen. After show the Window, the shortcut is available and an alert is showed.

Well, the issue to me is the remaining availability of the shortcut in scenarios where that shortcut must do not exist any more:

1. - When the window is close normally.
2. - When Null window button is execute, and after that if you use "Alt+T" then the alert is showed twice, and so on as many time you switch between the Null and Show buttons.
3. - Same behavior as (2) even if `destroy()` method of window is called explicitly.
4. - On playground if "Run" button is clicked several times, also equal times is showed alert after use the shortcut.

Thanks no all for your time. :)

[On Playground](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22qx.Class.define('my.Window'%252C%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520extend%253A%2520qx.ui.window.Window%252C%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520construct%253A%2520function(caption%252C%2520icon)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.base(arguments%252C%2520caption%252C%2520icon)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Basic())%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__btn%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button('Shortcut%2520Test')%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__cmd%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.command.Command('Alt%252BT')%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__cmd.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%2520alert('FOOBAR')%253B%2520%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__btn.setCommand(this.__cmd)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.add(this.__btn)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520members%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520__btn%253A%2520null%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520__cmd%253A%2520null%250A%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520destruct%253A%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__cmd%2520%253D%2520null%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250Aqx.Class.define('my.Compo'%252C%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520extend%253A%2520qx.ui.container.Composite%252C%250A%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520construct%253A%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.base(arguments)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.HBox())%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__btnShow%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Show%2520Window%2522%252C%2520%2522icon%252F22%252Fapps%252Finternet-web-browser.png%2522)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__btnDestroy%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button('Destroy%2520window')%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__btnNull%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button('Null%2520window')%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__btnDestroy.addListener('execute'%252C%2520function()%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window.destroy()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window%2520%253D%2520null%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__btnNull.addListener('execute'%252C%2520function()%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window%2520%253D%2520null%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__btnShow.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if(this.__window)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.info('Window%2520exist')%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window.open()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window.center()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520else%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.info('Window%2520do%2520not%2520exist!')%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window%2520%253D%2520new%2520my.Window(%2522Shortcut%2520test%2520window%2522)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window.setWidth(300)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window.setHeight(200)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window.setShowMinimize(false)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window.open()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__window.center()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.add(this.__btnShow)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.add(this.__btnDestroy)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.add(this.__btnNull)%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520members%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520__btnShow%253A%2520null%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520__btnDestroy%253A%2520null%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520__window%253A%2520null%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520compo%2520%253D%2520new%2520my.Compo()%253B%250Athis.getRoot().add(compo)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *qx.ui.command.Command* wraps the *qx.bom.Shortcut* that [attaches 2 listeners](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/bom/Shortcut.js#L190) to document element. When you close the window *qx.ui.command.Command* instance was not set inactive or destroyed. You'll have to handle the window close event properly.

```
destruct: function() 
{
 this.__cmd = null;
}
```

it does not destroy the command. If you try:

`qx.core.ObjectRegistry.fromHashCode("the command object hash code").getActive()`

You will find that it exists and is active. You forgot to destroy the command calling

`this.__cmd.dispose()`

Qooxdoo Playground App object registry is not initialized every time someone pushes "Run". So, qooxdoo object's lifetime is bound to page lifetime or a disposal event.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Actually I add to listeners on Window constructor:

    this.addListener('appear', function() { this.__btn.setCommand(this.getCmd()); }, this);
    this.addListener('close', function() { this.getCmd().dispose(); }, this);

and call dispose on destructor:

   destruct: function() {
     this.__cmd.dispose();
   }

With this works as expected. :D